# How to detect signal handler change in C?

Tags: c, gcc, signals, segmentation-fault

In my system I load multiple shared objects which install SIGSEGV handlers in the library constructors while calling dlopen.I need to issue a warning everytime a sigaction is called and the signal handler gets changed?

Comment: Is there a callback mechanism which the kernel provides to check routine changes in signals?

Comment: I am not sure but using the sigaction we can get the old mask of signal using the third parameter we are passing to sigaction. So for that pass the NULL to the second argument. Then variable for third argument. Using that structure members we can get that.

Comment: I am aware of that procedure.Is there a system mechanism t detect that.I am unaware when a sigaction maybe called.It depends on the number of shared objects being loaded as I have mentioned in the description above.